# Migrate docker-compose files with `links` directrive

Tags: docker-compose

I have a `docker.compose.yml` file that works as expected when I execute `docker-compose up` in its parent directory.

My problem is that it's an old version compose file, and I need to integrate its containers into another compose file. The old file has the following structure:

```
service1:
   ...
service2:
   ...
```

While the target docker-compose.yml has the following structure:

```
version: '2.3'

services:

   service1:
      ...
   service2:
      ...
```

So, my problem is that the old version file relies on parameter `links`. I don't quite understand what is its function. I see few documentation online, and all that the docs says is that the links are replaced by networks. Good, but what is the function of links? How could I replace it, so I don't use (about to get) deprecated features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

You can just delete the link section of the old-version docker compose file and access the services from other container by their names.

You can optionally define networks in order to define which service will be available to the others by placing them in the same network. E.g. :

```
networks:
  my_network_1:
    driver: bridge
  my_network_2:
    driver: bridge

services:
  service_1:
    networks:
      - my_network_1
  service_2:
    networks:
      - my_network_1
  service_3:
    networks:
      - my_network_2
```

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty clear. There is just one point that is not covered (I should have included it in my original question), what about aliases? If links are `links: -service1:service1 -service2:s2`, how should I migrate this?

Comment: If your services are called service1 and service2 just delete the links section. If not, wherever service1 and service2 is used, use the service names accordingly. (You can mark the answer as accepted if you want (: )